# Why do I keep getting a segmentation dump?

Tags: c

I have to create a program that sorts one word alphabetically and must be done so using arrays and pointers.

I tried removing the size of the array and allocating memory, but that gave me the same segmentation fault. I don't know if the issue is with passing the array to the function or the bubble sort. I added a print statement in the function so I assume I'm passing the array correctly. When pancake is entered it does print a within the function. I'm leaning more towards the bubble sort causing the issue because I can remove that and it gets rid of the segmentation fault.

```
void main(void)
{
  int num;
  double swap1 = 18.4 , swap2 = 95.73;
  char theString[50];
  char beginning, ending;
  printf("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  doubleme(&num);
  printf("%d is the value you entered doubled.\n", num);
  printf("Before swapping value a is %lf and value b is %lf\n", swap1, swap2);
  swap(&swap1, &swap2);
  printf("After swapping value a is %lf and value b is %lf\n", swap1, swap2);
  printf("Enter a word and I will tell you the first and last character of the alphabet within it.\n");
  scanf("%s", theString);
  firstLast(theString, &beginning, &ending);
  printf("%s is the first character and %s is the last.\n", beginning, ending);
}

void doubleme(int *x)
{
  *x = 2 * *x;
}

void swap(double *a, double *b)
{
  double temp;
  temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void firstLast(char theString[], char *first, char *last)
{
  int i, j, n;
  n = strlen(theString);
  char temp;
  printf("%c\n", theString[4]);
  for(i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < (n - 1); j++)
    {
      if(theString[j] > theString[(j+1)])
      {
        temp = theString[j];
        theString[j] = theString[(j+1)];
        theString[(j+1)] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  *first = theString[0];
  *last = theString[(n-1)];
}
```

I need the function to sort any string entered and return the values to the main using arrays and pointers.

Comment: What's `doubleme`? What's `swap`? Why are you passing a `char` to `printf` for `%s`? My guess is that the latter is causing the problem, use `%c` to print a `char`.

Comment: doubleme and swap are other functions that had to be used for this assignment they're working fine I could post them if you'd like to see those as well. So far in class we've only been shown how to read in a string using scanf. If there is a better way I'm open to learning. I'm printing the statement because I was testing the same word pancake to see if I can get the desired results. I believe the array is being passed correctly because I get 'a' when printing theString[4].

Comment: @ChristianHeaven Don't assume the problem isn't at certain places. It's not uncommon that the problem is in the code that is not posted.

Comment: You should always turn on compiler warnings. It should give you some diagnosticts about mismatch of format specifiers ans provided parameters.

Comment: You should definitely be using an IDE with compiler warnings switched ON. That would have stopped your code crashing.  I would have found it useful if you included all the code `doubleme()`, `swap()`, so I could run it through a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Blaze that's what was wrong the entire time. I spent three hours looking at this code and didn't even think to look at the print statement back in main.

Comment: Running your program in a debugger should reveal the location of the crash within seconds. Using a debugger is a step that you should include in your process to solve bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are cheating your compiler.
You claim to provide the address of a string but instead you pass a single character for `%s` format specifier.

```
  char beginning, ending;

  printf("%s is the first character and %s is the last.\n", beginning, ending);
```

This will treat the value of that character as an address and try to read from there.
This is undefined behaviour